# Distribute items into buckets

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to figure out how to place a number of items into buckets evenly.

I possess 302 items and I aim to distribute these items into buckets. I need to determine the number of buckets required, ensuring that each bucket holds at least one item and that every item is accounted for in a bucket. My preference is to have no fewer than 10 and no more than 60 buckets.

Tomorrow, the number of items will increase to 303, and the following day it will be 304. Therefore, the equation must remain adaptable to provide the correct number of buckets as the item count changes.

Comment: Simply write down the divisors of $302$, we get $1,2,151,302$. This means you can either have $302$ buckets with $1$ item in all of them, $151$ buckets with $2$ items, $2$ buckets with $151$ or $1$ bucket with $302$ items. Your preference cannot be satisfied in this case. Adapting this method for $n$ items: find $x$ and $y$ such that $x\cdot y=n$, then you can have $x$ buckets with each $y$ items in them. You can use a few criteria to choose which $x$ you want.

Comment: @jorisperrenet Not sure. For example 18 is a good number (and I am sure there are others?) of buckets because: 

buckets: 1...17 have 17 items, totalling = 289
bucket 18 has 13 items
sum of all to: 302

I'm after the formula to arrive at the number 18?

Comment: You need to tell what makes a good distribution.  Why would your $17$ buckets with $17$ items each and $1$ bucket with $13$ items be better than $28$ buckets with $10$ items each and $2$ buckets with $11$ items each?

Comment: The higher the number the better.

Think I just worked out the best number would be 51